# Do standard "order" clauses in ActiveRecord require an index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, indexing

If I am applying scopes in `ActiveRecord` ordering by a column, e.g.

`User.order("name")`

Should I ensure an index is present on the `name` column? Or is the index only required if I'm doing a `where` clause.

Comment: It's definitely beneficial to have an index so that DBMS can use the index to order without extra sorting.

Comment: The answer depends on all sorts of things. For example: How often will you do this query (i.e. will the overhead of maintaining the index outweigh the cost of sorting without an index)? What does your database say when you check the query plan with and without the index? You probably do want the index but maybe not, it depends on what you're doing and what your data looks like.

Comment: @muistooshort is there an easy to way to check using Rails if an index would be beneficial? Load up a pile of records and query in some fashion?

Comment: The easiest way would be to load up a pile of records, figure out what sorts of SQL you'll be using, and then use your database's version of EXPLAIN to see what the database thinks of your SQL. Basically, push Rails out of the way and get your hands dirty. IMO you should be thinking of your database as a separate application anyway; I know that Rails wants to pretend that the database doesn't really exist on its own but that's a silly attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether an index can be used in place of a sort operation depends on a few different factors:

1. Whether it's more cost effective to do so. If an index is going to be used to access the required rows then that of course helps, but if you want to select all the people with first name "John" and order by their date of birth then you'd probably need a composite index on first_name and date_of_birth. An index on date_of_birth alone would not be enough.
2. Whether the index is ordered the same as the required order. This is more complex, and applies to character strings. By default many indexes are binary ordered, so all uppercase letters sort lower than all lowercase letters in the ASCII data set. This is unlikely to be the order you want, and it gets even more complex for i18n text, where different languages sort special characters (with accents for example) in different ways. You may need to look into whether your RDBMS supports indexes with the ordering that you want for your character set. Dates and numbers do not have this issue of course.

Long-story-short the index you create by default may not be suitable for ordering the data, and even if it is, it may not be the most cost effective way of accessing the table.

Best approach though -- test it and see, and if you are surprised by an index not being used, think about the above factors.